# .Net not finding referenced dependency required by Nuget package

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, dependencies, nuget

We recently setup a local nuget server to improve our handling of dependencies within our projects. To package and push our libraries, we use the "new" project format in Visual Studio and a marketplace addon called NuPack-Nuget Packager.

Workflow for development is then to create a new project and pull the required dependencies.

Now we got a strange behavior on all workplaces.

Eg. we have 2 libraries: LibA (Version 1.1.0) and LibB (Version 2.5.0) 
where LibB depends on LibA and references it as a project reference. 
I have my project referencing LibB (Version 2.5.0) via Nuget.

When I change LibB (now Version 2.5.1) and push it  to our Nuget and update the reference in my project everything appears to work fine, the project builds and has no errors, but at runtime, once code is executed that references LibA (still Version 1.1.0, no changes made) I get a FileNotFound Exception: Assembly LibA, AssemblyVersion 1.1.0 could not be found.

The only workaround for now is to package a new LibA as Version 1.1.1 (no code changes) and push it to the nuget server and update the reference in my project to Version 1.1.1 .

Does anyone know a cause / a solution to this?

**EDIT** Things that do not solve the problem:

- Clean / Rebuild the solution (neither Dependencies nor Project)
- Update-Package -reinstall in package manager commandline
- Clearing Nuget caches and restoring all dependencies
- Removing and readding nuget reference in project by hand

**EDIT** Exact error message (Assembly name changed)

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Lib.A.Namespace.1.1, Version=1.1.7, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden.'

Translation of the last part: "File could not be found"

**EDIT** All dependencies are compiled as AnyCPU for NetStandard2.0

Comment: Is LibB referencing LibA via project reference. Or is LibA installed as a nuget dependency into LibB?

Comment: LibB references LibA via project reference. 
The error still persists when using a nuget reference though.

Comment: What is the exact error message? BTW something like this appeared in my company when a referenced lib or any of it's dependencies was compiled to x86 and the referencing lib was compiled to x64 or vice-versa.

Comment: Does your nuget package LibB (Version 2.5.1) contain **nuget dependency** LibA (Version 1.1.0) rather than project reference?

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT LibB definitly (just checked again) references LibA by project reference.

Comment: @user3746886, Thanks for your reply. I know that your LibB  references LibA by project reference, but I want to know if the nuget package LibB have dependencies LibA **in the nuget package**, when you create the nuget package LibB, you should add the LibA as dependencies. And have you add the nuget package LibA in the nuget feed? If my comment not easy to be understood, I can convert it to the answer with more info.

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT Oh sorry I missunderstood. LibA is listed as a NETStandard2.0 dependency (Version >= ...) for LibB nuget feed.
LibA does exist as a seperate nuget feed.
I do not see how I could add LibA as a dependency for LibB (any more than it is already) ?

Comment: @user3746886,what are your project type for your LibB and LibA, .net framework or .NETStandard? Before use the workaround, have you add the nuget package LibA to your project separately?

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT LibA and LibB are NetStandard2.0, my project is Net.Core 2.1.
The error persists even if I add the dependency as nuget instead of project reference.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185247/discussion-between-leo-liu-msft-and-user3746886).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem has been identified.** 
NuPack-Nuget Packager is 'at fault' here.
For anyone stumbling upon this in the future:

Our problem was the way the NuPack-Nuget Packager works. 
While the workflow seems to be handy (set Assemblyversion, set output dir, set nuget server, finished), the project will not be build for the package deployment and thus relies on the previous build, which internally still holds the previous AssemblyVersion.

We finally got to the solution after finding out we were pulling obsolete references (found in the User/.Nuget/Packages folder).

We did not come up with a final, one step solution for build, package and deploy yet.